# Suppose a distribution function $F(x)$, let $A(y) := \{s: F(s) \ge y\}$, show $A(y)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose a distribution function $F(x)$, let $A(y) := \{s: F(s) \ge y\}$, show $A(y)$ is closed. My textbook proves this by following:

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text {If } s_{n} \in A(y), \text { and } s_{n} \downarrow s, \text { then by right continuity }} \\ {\qquad y \leq F\left(s_{n}\right) \downarrow F(s)} \\ {\text { so } F(s) \geq y \text { and } s \in A(y) \text { . If } s_{n} \uparrow s \text { and } s_{n} \in A(y) \text { , then }} \\ {\qquad y \leq F\left(s_{n}\right) \uparrow F(s-) \leq F(s)} \\ {\text { and } y \leq F(s) \text { implies } s \in A(y)}\end{array}
$$

I know there is a proposition

> a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is closed iff every convergent sequence in $A$ converges in $A$

But the prove above only involves monotonic convergent sequence

Comment: Any sequence has a monotone subsequence, so the statement might as well be rephrased as $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed iff every convergent montone sequence in $A$ converges in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem:** If $A\subset\mathbb R$ is such that, for every monotonic convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\in A$, then $A$ is closed.

**Proof:** Suppose that $A$ is not closed. Take $a\in A^\complement$ such that$$(\forall \varepsilon>0):(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\cap A\neq\emptyset.$$For each $n\in\mathbb N$, take $a_n\in(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n)\cap A$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. But every sequence has a monotonic subsequence. If you take such a monotonic subsequence of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, it will still converge to $a$. But this is impossible, since we are assuming that, for every monotonic convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\in A$. Therefore, a contradiction was reached.